# Pulling out particular buildings and their size variables from a map

Tags: c#

ㅤ
Hello. As an amateur coder, i'm doing some game mods etc.
I have these almost identical and kind of spacious methods, and i wonder if there is any way to make them less bloaty?
ㅤ
I'm curious about this for future instances too.

My original methods are basically for pulling out particular buildings from the map, with the copy of the same method *(with just a different last line)* I also pull a variable from the buildings.

The original code makes more sense, but i tried to make it similar and runable as much as i can.
So the options i can come up with are;

- Two same big methods with only one last line different.  *The good (fat)*.
- An extra iterator loop through the first method, when it can be done without it.  *The bad*.
- Using a generic method i just learned about. But i think it is...  *The ugly*.
  ㅤ
  The question is; Is there a better way here to make this code more compact and readable.
  ㅤ
  ㅤ*This is my first question here. And sory for the weird code typing.*

ㅤ

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class World { public HashSet<Map> maps = new HashSet<Map>(){new Map()}; }
    public class Map { public HashSet<Coordinates> coordinates = new HashSet<Coordinates>(){new Coordinates()}; }
    public class Coordinates { public HashSet<Level> levels = new HashSet<Level>(){new Level()}; }
    public class Level { public HashSet<Thing> things = new HashSet<Thing>(){new Thing()}; }
    public class Thing { public HashSet<Building> buildings = new HashSet<Building>(){new Building(), new Building()};}
    public class Building { public int Size; }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Building> GetBuildings(this World w) // Two Same Big Methods
        {
            foreach (Map m in w.maps)
                foreach(Coordinates c in m.coordinates)
                    foreach(Level l in c.levels)
                        foreach(Thing t in l.things)
                            foreach(Building b in t.buildings)
                            { yield return b; } // with a little belly.
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> GetSizes(this World w) // Same Big
        {
            foreach (Map m in w.maps)
                foreach(Coordinates c in m.coordinates)
                    foreach(Level l in c.levels)
                        foreach(Thing t in l.things)
                            foreach(Building b in t.buildings)
                            { yield return b.Size; }    // the belly.
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> GetSizesExtra(this World w) // Using an extra loop just for the looks? 
        {                                                          // Not even that much good looking. Bad.
            foreach (Building b in w.GetBuildings()) { yield return b.Size; }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> GetBThings<T>(this World w) // The ugly. I really don't like the looks here.
        {                                                       // I don't know much but it doesn't look like a appropriate option too.
            foreach (Map m in w.maps)
                foreach(Coordinates c in m.coordinates)
                    foreach(Level l in c.levels)
                        foreach(Thing t in l.things)
                            foreach(Building b in t.buildings)
                            {
                                if (typeof(T) == typeof(Building)) { yield return (T)Convert.ChangeType(b, typeof(T)); }
                                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) { yield return (T)Convert.ChangeType(b.Size, typeof(T)); }
                            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            World world = new World();
    
            IEnumerable<Building> big_buildings = world.GetBuildings();
            IEnumerable<int> big_sizes =  world.GetSizes(); // Running the big same methods
    
            IEnumerable<Building> extra_buildings = world.GetBuildings();
            IEnumerable<int> extra_sizes = world.GetSizesExtra(); // Running it with extra loop

            IEnumerable<Building> weird_buildings = world.GetBThings<Building>();
            IEnumerable<int> weird_sizes =  world.GetBThings<int>(); // Running it with generics
    

        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please tell us what you aim to accomplish with this code or your application? Is this all the code of your classes? If there is no specialized functionality in the classes, why not make a hierarchy of tree nodes without caring what type of nodes they are?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Classes have lots of specialized functionality, but they're from a whole game I'm modding, Rimworld.
My original methods are basically for pulling out particular buildings from the map,
with the copy of the same method (with just a different last line) I also pull a variable from the buildings.
What I'm asking is, looking at these methods just as they are, could there be a better way to avoid duplications.

Comment: you could implement `GetThings` extension, then use it with `GetBuildings` and `GetSizes` and this should be enough to remove the `GetSizesExtra` and `GetBThings`.

Comment: Thanks, @isR5. I thought maybe there might be a more sophisticated way to it, but i guess that's all there is. I'll go with the extension xd.

Comment: Sory, missed the edit time @isR5. 
Wouldn't it be something like; 
        foreach (Building b in w.GetThings()) { Buildings.Add(b); } 
And isn't there an extra loop use going on here?

Comment: @blues if you have `Building` you can get all its nested public objects including the `Size` property. So, why you won't simplify it to just `GetBuildings` and let the caller decide what to do with it. If caller needs the all sizes, then simply caller can do `world.GetBuildings().Select(x=> x.Size).ToList();` so returning the `Building` is enough here.

Comment: Yes, I just did something similar myself, @isR5 :)    
world.GetBuildings().ConvertAll(x => x.Size).ToHashSet(); I'll try it with Select too, and have some reed on the stuff.
Thanks for your help and time:)

Comment: I read about the question asking topics, I tried my best with the title. Maybe because it's my first question ever, i think this is all i can be explanatory enough without turning my title into a whole paragraph.
Since my original code is a game mod, the original aim of the code is too irrelevant with reality and impossible to run as it is, so i tried my best to write a code with similar objective and is run-able.
So, how is this new one. If it's too bad, can you give me an example title for this specific topic, @BCdotWEB.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in the comments, if you just implement an extension method for `GetThings` then you can reuse it for `GetBuildings` and `GetSizes`.

Example :

```
public static class WorldExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Thing> GetThings(this World world) // Two Same Big Methods
    {
        if(world is null) yield break;
        
        foreach (Map map in world.maps)
        {
            foreach(Coordinates coordinate in map.coordinates)
            {
                foreach(Level level in coordinate.levels)
                {
                    foreach(Thing thing in level.things)
                    {
                        yield return thing;
                    }                   
                }               
            }       
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Thing> GetBuildings(this World world)
    {
        if(world is null) yield break;
        
        foreach (Thing thing in world.GetThings())
        {
            foreach(Building building in thing.buildings)
            {
                yield return building;                  
            }
        }           
    }
    
    
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetSizes(this World world) 
    {
        if(world is null) yield break;
        
        foreach (Thing thing in world.GetThings())
        {
            foreach(Building building in thing.buildings)
            {
                yield return building.Size;
            }
        
        }       
    }
    
}
```

However, Since we have `GetBuildings` we know that we will get the object `Building` and its nested public objects including the Size property.

Example :

```
var sizes = world.GetBuildings().Select(x=> x.Size).ToList();
```

In this case, `GetBuildings` would be enough, as it depends on the caller to decide what to do with it. unless if there is a heavy usage of `GetSizes` or you need to add some extra rules to resulting sizes, then it would be reasonable to have it along with `GetBuildings`.

Lastly, try your best to follow [**C# Coding Conventions**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions)

Comment: Thank you, "Select" thing was really helpful. My code literally evolved.
Honestly, I really don't feel like it and I'm nothing serious in this but, I'll try my best about the conventions too:)